# I can't understand the placement c=0 and l=0 in the following piece of code

Tags: c

I can't understand the placement c=0 and l=0 in the following piece of code.Here n is number of element in array a and m is number of element in array b.

```
for(i=2;i<=16;i++){
 c=0;
    for(j=0;j<2;j++)
    {
        if(i%a[j]==0)
        c++;
    }
    if(c==2)
    {
    l=0;
    for(k=0;k<3;k++)
    {
        if(b[k]%i==0)
            l++;
    }
    if(l==3)
        count++;}
}
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: It initializes a variable `c` with the value `0`.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm not sure what you're asking. This assigns the value 0 to the integer variable `c`.

Comment: I want to know the difference if i intialise c=0 at the starting of the program.

Comment: The difference is it wouldn't be set to zero on each iteration of the outer loop.

Comment: Please make a [mcve] and double-check that you are really looking at C. Also please explain what you mean by "c=0". Why it is set to 0 inside the outer loop? Why it is 0 at the end of your program? Why it is there and not elsewhere? What do you observe which you want explained?

Comment: Corrected the code. Posted that previous code by fault. Sorry

Comment: Ah. Looks much more like C now. And now make a MCVE please and ask a clearer question. If you cannot ask clear, make at least an MCVE, that will help us guess what you are asking about.

Comment: Could you tell us what the program in total is doing or what it is supposed to do? If it fails to do as expected, then please explain both. Ideally also explain your understanding/interpretation of the difference.

Comment: What I am trying to make clear to you is that without much more information nobody will be able to give you a better answer than Tom Karzes in the comment above. And I somehow feel that it is not the answer you are looking for.

Comment: I am just a beginner so i see codes in which the variable is initialised in the starting of the code like int main(){int c=0}. However in this code the variable c is initialised inside the for loop. Why? I mean what result will it give and how will it be different from initialised the variable at the starting of the code? That code is just a piece for finding total number of lcm of all the element in an array a.

Comment: We cannot tell you without seeing more of the code. But you might be confusing "initialising" with "resetting". As Tom wrote, the `c=0` where it is now will not only initialise it before the first `c++`, it will also reset it to 0 each time the outer loop starts the inner loop again.

Comment: With the shown code this means that the value of c after the first inner loop is completly lost, because the code you show does not do anything with it before it is reset. But if you show more code we might point out to you what useful things are done with it before that happens.

Comment: Please study [tour], [ask], https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/   , https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: May I ask the meaning of **l=0;** which is also inside the loop?

Comment: Changed the position of l=0 for better understanding.

Comment: Maybe this article could help: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-rules-in-c/ (scroll down to `block scope`). I don't know how relevant the context of your piece of code is; generally, it's easier to read if you don't use magic numbers or variables.

Comment: Used constants wherever possible. Maybe you will understand the code now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to what I read in the comments, what seem to puzzle yourself are so-called **local variables**.

When you define a variable somewhere, its scope actually spans only to the limits of the block it's written into (from `{` to `}`). Its space is dynamically reserved in the stack at the moment you enter the block and is automatically released when you leave it, as the stack frame is destroyed.

It's always a good idea to declare variables only where they're really used instead of gathering all declaration at top of program. First because you ensure this way that your memory will be allocated only when you need it and will be automatically released as soon as possible. Then because it avoids polluting the namespace with identifiers which could be evaluated where they're not relevant, making bugs harder to find.

Comment: they are not declared there. you are wrong

Comment: Please check the edition history. The code has been altered 7 times since I posted this answer. What you see no longer has much to do with the original post.